# Android app crashing after loading project on a different computer

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been storing my project in DropBox to share across computers so I can work from my laptop upstairs. Everything worked fine on my PC, then I went and loaded the project on my laptop and it just crashed when I tried to run it so I gave up and came back to my PC, but now it isn't working there either. It was working fine, I didn't change anything about the code at all. but now I get the error below.

No matter how many gradle syncs and updates and everything that I try I can't figure out how to fix. In addition to fixing this, how am I supposed to work on the same project on multiple PC's without breaking everything?

I ran a Gradle Clean and Sync but it didn't seem to work that time either. Also I didn't even realize I was using AsyncTask, so I'll look at that.

Since I'm not sure exactly what the stack trace is, here's my whole LogCat :)

```
03-10 14:25:41.849 4830-4830/com.mydomain.myapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
03-10 14:25:41.960 4830-4830/com.mydomain.myapp I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
03-10 14:25:41.961 4830-4830/com.mydomain.myapp I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
03-10 14:25:41.966 4830-4870/com.mydomain.myapp V/FA: Using measurement service
03-10 14:25:41.966 4830-4870/com.mydomain.myapp V/FA: Connecting to remote service
03-10 14:25:41.967 4830-4870/com.mydomain.myapp V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 4313744
03-10 14:25:41.977 4830-5248/com.mydomain.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
     Process: com.mydomain.myapp, PID: 4830
     java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
      Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{36fd80a 4830:com.mydomain.myapp/u0a17} (pid=4830, uid=10017) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
         at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3550)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
         at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2018)
         at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1468)
         at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:475)
         at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:64)
         at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:56)
         at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
         at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
         at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:66)
         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
03-10 14:25:41.980 4830-5250/com.mydomain.myapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

     [ 03-10 14:25:41.982  4830: 4830 D/         ]
     HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7effab5dc260, tid 4830
03-10 14:25:42.283 4830-4830/com.mydomain.myapp D/MainActivity: onAuthStateChanged:signed_out
03-10 14:25:42.314 4830-5250/com.mydomain.myapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-10 14:25:42.314 4830-5250/com.mydomain.myapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
03-10 14:25:42.434 4830-4870/com.mydomain.myapp V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 469
03-10 14:25:42.435 4830-4870/com.mydomain.myapp V/FA: Using measurement service
03-10 14:25:42.435 4830-4870/com.mydomain.myapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
03-10 14:25:42.436 4830-4870/com.mydomain.myapp V/FA: Activity paused, time: 4314214
03-10 14:25:42.457 4830-4870/com.mydomain.myapp D/FA: Connected to remote service
03-10 14:25:42.457 4830-4870/com.mydomain.myapp V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
03-10 14:25:42.526 4830-4830/com.mydomain.myapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
03-10 14:25:42.640 4830-5250/com.mydomain.myapp E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7effa40972a0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, on the original computer on which this project last worked, try a gradle 'clean' and then a build. If that doesn't work, it probably means that you changed the code since it last worked. Try to figure out what you changed, and undo that.

Second, AsyncTask is the source of a lot of headaches (and crashes), because it holds a reference to the Activity from which it was started, but is not part of the Activity's lifecycle, so can operate on the Activity after the Activity has been destroyed. My suggestion - don't use AsyncTask - regardless of what you are using it for, there is almost always a better way. Post your stacktrace here, and we might be able to help you figure out what the problem is.

As far as sharing code, use a version control system. GitHub is good, and it's free. Proper use of it would also let you easily roll your code back to the point where it last worked.

=====

Ok, so looking at the stacktrace that you posted from your logcat, we see:

java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Caused by: **java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{36fd80a 4830:com.mydomain.myapp/u0a17} (pid=4830, uid=10017) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS**

So, it looks like you are attempting to access the ContactsProvider, but haven't put the READ_CONTACTS permission in your manifest.

Comment: Clean/build didn't seem to work. I posted more info above, does that help at all?

Comment: looks like you're missing the READ_CONTACTS permission. See additional info above.